# Taking Down Helicopters

Tags: nintendo-wii, call-of-duty-black-ops

With the M72 Law, when I look lock onto an attack helicopter and fire, the helicopter makes an evasive maneuver and I miss.

It seems like the best way to take down a helicopter is just to line it up without the scope and fire, is that the best way.  I've had some success with this.  Are there any other tips for taking down a chopper?

Comment: Do a barrel roll

Comment: What do you mean a barrel roll?

Comment: http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/do-a-barrel-roll

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There really isn't a good way to hit a helicopter with the M72 Law, the first rocket is always going to miss. No matter who fired it, either because the helicopter moved or it shot out flares. Your best bet to taking out a helicopter with the M72 is being the second person to fire at the helicopter. Or you could always just equip the Strela-3 which has two rockets rather than just the one.

Comment: The helicopter can't "move" to evade a locked-on M72 projectile. The first one always misses, and the second one always hits.

Answer (score 3):

What I've found is that on the first shot towards it, countermeasures will be launched from a chopper.

Take another shot or die & respawn, your second missile will hit bang on target.

Answer (score 0):

It's also easier to have Scavenger Perk since you will have 2 rockets, so your first shot is bound to miss (if it scatters flares), then on your second shot you are more likely to shoot it down.

Also, make sure you're focusing on the sight with the helicopter, shoot when you get rapid vibration on the controller so you will know the rocket is likely to shoot it down when it's aimed at the helicopter on your second shot.

Comment: Last I checked Scavenger doesn't replenish equipment, which the game considers launcher rockets to be, the only way to get full equipment reloads is to get a resupply package from a care package drop.

Comment: My mistake, Scavenger Pro enables more ammo stock when the game starts/respawns. You will be equipped with two rockets. You are correct, that the Scavenger will not replenish the rockets, but still, you start with two rockets.

Answer (score 0):

All air support helicopters (Attack Helicopter, Chopper Gunner, and Gunship) have one signal flare to shoot off **if and only if there is a guided missile coming after it**. You can take down a helicopter even if it has a flare left if the thing you're shooting at it does more damage than the helicopter has left.